# Creating multiple tables in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I'm in the process of learning ReactJS. Right now I'm learning how tables work. Right now, I have a single working table that is loaded with JSON data, but I want to create a second table. Right now I keep running into this error:

> Module build failed: D:/Documents/Web
>   Programming/React/my-app/src/App.js: Duplicate declaration "Table"

I've tried to rename the `Table` class, but that throws additional errors. What would be the best way to handle multiple tables using this approach?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./CSS/App.css";
import Table1 from "./Table1";
import Axios from 'axios';
import CoinTable from './components/coin-table'
import coinData from './data/coins.json'
//import DBConfig from "./API/DBConfig"; // can't do because you need to have the api 

// creates a "template" of the components that will be used
// Header and Content need to be capitalized in order to work
class App extends Component
{
  render()
  {
    return( // left paren has to go there otherwise it'll fail out
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Content/> 
        <Table/>
        <Table/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends Component
{
  render()
  {
    return(
      <div>
        <center><h1>Learning React</h1></center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Content extends Component {
  render() 
  {
    return (
        <div>
           <h2>Content</h2>
           <p>The content text!!</p>
        </div>
     );
  };
};

// coin information table
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p className="Table-header">Coin Information</p>
        <Table1 data={coinData}/>
      </div>
    );
  };
}; 

// Actor information table
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App2">
        <p className="Table-header">Actor Table</p>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

**EDIT: What I get when I change the class names**

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Module build failed: D:/Documents/Web Programming/React/my-app/src/App.js: Duplicate declaration "Table"

  83 |
  84 | // Actor information table
> 85 | class Table extends Component {
     |       ^
  86 |   render() {
  87 |     return (
  88 |       <div className="App2">
Compiling...
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Module build failed: D:/Documents/Web Programming/React/my-app/src/App.js: Duplicate declaration "CoinTable"

  72 |
  73 | // coin information table
> 74 | class CoinTable extends Component {
     |       ^
  75 |   render() {
  76 |     return (
  77 |       <div className="App">
Compiling...
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Module build failed: D:/Documents/Web Programming/React/my-app/src/App.js: Duplicate declaration "CoinTable"

  72 |
  73 | // coin information table
> 74 | class CoinTable extends Component {
     |       ^
  75 |   render() {
  76 |     return (
  77 |       <div className="App">
```

Comment: Because you have two classes with same name Table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two classes with same name and thats why you get duplication error

You also need to export Content, CoinTable, ActorTable like I did below

Try with below code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./CSS/App.css";
import Table1 from "./Table1";
import Axios from 'axios';
//import CoinTable from './components/coin-table'
import coinData from './data/coins.json'
//import DBConfig from "./API/DBConfig"; // can't do because you need to have the api 

// creates a "template" of the components that will be used
// Header and Content need to be capitalized in order to work
class App extends Component
{
  render()
  {
    return( // left paren has to go there otherwise it'll fail out
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Content/> 
        <CoinTable/>
        <ActorTable/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class Header extends Component
{
  render()
  {
    return(
      <div>
        <center><h1>Learning React</h1></center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class Content extends Component {
  render() 
  {
    return (
        <div>
           <h2>Content</h2>
           <p>The content text!!</p>
        </div>
     );
  };
};
// coin information table
export class CoinTable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p className="Table-header">Coin Information</p>
        <Table1 data={coinData}/>
      </div>
    );
  };
}; 

// Actor information table
export class ActorTable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App2">
        <p className="Table-header">Actor Table</p>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

Comment: That's actually what I've tried - I'll update my question with the error that I get.

Comment: @Matt You need to export the components so that they will be available when you call them in the other component render though the components are declared within .js file you still need to export them so that they will be available

Comment: @Matt I just updated my code. Give a try now It would work

Comment: Awesome - that works. I guess that's what I get for using a bunch of different tutorials. Cheers!

Comment: @Matt you are welcome :) Please do upvote and accept the provided answer if it resolves the issue

Comment: Cool. Thank you :)